# Extracting a value from an option inside an option in Scala

Tags: scala, slick

Given the following:

```
val x = Some(Some(1))
```

What would be the cleanest way to get the 1 (or -1 if the one did not exist)?

I'm creating an object instance from a tuple returned from a database query. One of the values in the tuple looks like this, so I would like a nice short 'one liner' to just get the value or set a parameter to -1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x.flatten` is what you are looking for. Here it will give you `Some(1)`.
If you really want to get `-1` for the case where "*the one did not exist*", just do `x.flatten.getOrElse(-1)`:

```
scala> Some(Some(1)).flatten.getOrElse(-1)
res1: Int = 1
scala> Some(None).flatten.getOrElse(-1)
res2: Int = -1
scala> None.flatten.getOrElse(-1)
res3: Int = -1
```

Comment: Flatten!!! I've read it, I've seen it, I've used it... now just to remember it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

for-comprehensions are often a very readable way to use these kinds of nested structures:

```
  val x = Some(Some(1))
  val result = for {
    firstLevel <- x
    secondLevel <- firstLevel
  } yield {
    // We've got an int, now transform it!
    (secondLevel * 100).toString
  }
```

The result is an Option[String], and the transformation only happens when you have two Some(s).

You can also use pattern matching:

```
  val result2 = for {
    Some(v) <- x
  } yield {
    // We've got a int, now transform it!
    (v * 100).toString
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not a "one-liner" you could make a function to extract the value. If you make it generic and pass in the default value it might be pretty handy.

```
scala> def fetchFromOptions[A](default: A)(x: Option[Option[A]]) = x match {
     | case Some(Some(a)) => a
     | case _ => default
     | }
fetchFromOptions: [A](default: A)(x: Option[Option[A]])A

scala> fetchFromOptions(-1)(Some(Some(1)))
res0: Int = 1

scala> fetchFromOptions(-1)(Some(None))
res1: Int = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with:

```
scala> val x = Some(Some(1))
x: Some[Some[Int]] = Some(Some(1))

scala> val y = x.map(_.getOrElse(-1)).get
y: Int = 1

scala> val x = Some(None)
x: Some[None.type] = Some(None)

scala> val y = x.map(_.getOrElse(-1)).get
y: Int = -1
```

This only works when your first-level *Some* is not *None*

Comment: +1 That's exactly one of the roads I took ;-) That, and 'match', but I knew there was a way to get it in one simple go, but could not recall how. Flatten does the magic I was looking for though.

Comment: Yes the other solution is clearly nicer. I too always forget about flatten. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually know that its `Some(Some(1))`, then you can use the irrefutable pattern match notation:

```
scala> val ssi1 = Some(Some(1))
ssi1: Some[Some[Int]] = Some(Some(1))

scala> val Some(Some(i1)) = ssi1
i1: Int = 1
```

If there may be any of the possible `None` in the mix, then you have to use the more cautious and verbose forms suggested by others.

For those that find this a bizarre notation, think of it as what you'd write in a `case` in a `match` construct or `PartialFunction` literal to match against a scrutinee that is `Some(Some(1))`.